Displaying/Keeping previous Query Results VS Code
Is there a way to keep previous query results when running new scrips?
Whenever I run a new script in the same window the new results overwrite the old ones, but ideally I'd like to keep the old ones and a new tab would open with the recent output.

I'm making a switch from SQL Developer to VS Code, where I was previously able to have multiple results kept, when re-running a script (see pic2)

I tried the SQL developer extension for VS Code and MySQL, amongst browsing all the settings. Unfortunately, I cannot find the right setting for what I need.

No, not yet.
Not yet, as in we intend to build this feature into the SQL Developer extension for VS Code in a future release.
For now you'd use script output to retusn previous query results.

Right-click directly on your Query Results table and choose Export.
Set Export Destination to either File or Clipboard.
Click Export.
